# Find the $f(x)$ from the given information

Tags: functions, relations

So tomorrow I tackled a maths test where I faced a question which was saying,

> **Question**: Let $f:R-\{0,1\}\rightarrow R$ be a function satisfying the relation
>
> $$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=x$$
>
> for all $x\in R-\{0,1\}$
>
> **Find  $f(x)$?**

Till yet I tried so many replacements as like replacing $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$ and $x\rightarrow \frac{x-1}{x}$, but these are not the appropriate ones to get my answer.

These kind of questions are not new to me as I had solved many before and even asked one before to (**[here is it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789513/find-f2a-x-from-given-equation)**). But here my main issue is that I am not getting an appropriate replacements and that's the thing for which I had raised my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea if this might be useful, but if you denote $g(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}$ then $g^{-1}(x) = g(g(x)) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $g(g(g(x))) = x$.

Comment: I think I had got what you are really trying to say and believe me it provided me a great hint. Thanks @JoelCohen. I am going to answer my own question now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-1}{x}$. Then $g(g(x))=1-\frac{x}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$, $g(g(g(x)))=1-\frac{1-x}{1}=x$. Notice that $g(x)\neq 1$ and $g(x)\neq 0$ is $x\neq 1$. By assumption, we have $f(x)+f(g(x))=x$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0,1\right\}$, so we obtain the equations
$$f(x)+f(g(x))=x\qquad (1)$$
$$f(g(x))+f(g(g(x)))=g(x)\qquad(2)$$
$$f(g(g(x)))+f(g(g(g(x))))=g(g(x))\qquad (3)$$
We can calculate equation (1)-(2)+(3), and cancel the terms $f(g(x))$ and $f(g(g(x))$, thus obtaining
\begin{align*}
2f(x)&=f(x)+f(g(g(g(x))))=x-g(x)+g(g(x))=x-\frac{x-1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x^2(1-x)-(x-1)(1-x)+x}{x(1-x)}=\frac{x^2-x^3+x^2-2x+1+x}{x(1-x)}\\
&=\frac{x^3-2x^2+x-1}{x(x-1)}
\end{align*}

Comment: I think what you had shown is not $f(x)$, it's actually $2f(x)$. But anyway I got that. Thank you very much @Luiz.

Comment: @Alpha Well if you know what is $2f(x)$, then you know what is $f(x)$, right?

Comment: Yeah that's why I said I got it. That's not any kind of issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

I know that @Luiz had provided a great answer and I'll definitely mark his answer as the accepted answer but I think going with that much $f(g(g(g(x))))$ might be a confusing stuff, at least for me. So here I came up with my own answer which I think might also help others. So here it goes.

> **Answer**: Given,
>
> $$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=x\qquad---(1)$$
>
> In equation $(1)$ replacing $x\rightarrow \frac{x-1}{x}$, we get,
>
> $$f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x-1}{x}\qquad---(2)$$
>
> In equation $(1)$ replacing $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}$, we get,
>
> $$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\qquad---(3)$$
>
> So by equating $(1) - (2) + (3)$ we get,
>
> $$2f(x)=\left(x+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x-1}{x}\right)$$
>
> $$\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x-1}{x}\right)\qquad$$

Got it! :)